# Deploy Web Application on AWS EC2

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, jboss, amazon-ec2

I have a Web Application which requires MySQL, JAVA JDK and JBoss to be deployed to AWS EC2.
What are the best practices and best way to deploy this to the end customer? I have a few questions:

1. I will be using Amazon Linux AMI, is there any other recommended one to use?
2. Where is the best place to have the JBoss files when installing?
3. I need live backups of MySQL, what's the best way for me to do this? I would need to be able to retrieve and run this if anything crashes without loosing any data. What other alternatives are there then using Amazon RDS?

This is the first time I am deploying a web-app and would appreciate some input.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you considered elastic beanstalk? They don't support JBoss but if your app is not too tightly integrated it may be worth migrating off of JBoss to Tomcat. You will save a lot of time and configuration effort.

Comment: Thank anttix, I have been able to successfully deploy an app using Elastic Beanstalk but since this is JBoss I need to put a bit of time and configuration to deploy it successfully

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty broad. However, I'll take a shot at helping out.

With JBOSS, you might want to look at something like this:

http://aws.typepad.com/awsaktuell/2013/10/elastic-jboss-as-7-clustering-in-aws-using-ec2-s3-elb-and-chef.html

If you are willing to switch your container from JBOSS to Tomcat you can use Elastic Beanstalk (as it doesn't support the JBOSS container). This way all the database, autoscaling and backup will be taken care for you by Amazon.

You can check the AWS documentation on how deploy your Java app to a Tomcat container here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html

Comment: Thanks Rico, No we will be using JBoss for this. I have been able to deploy an app with Elastic Beanstalk successfully. What I need is to know where the JBoss file should be installed and what's the best way to have back ups of db which are persistent. I have come across Amazon RDS and also know there is an option using EBS, S3, where it take snapshots and saves it to S3, is there a way to bypass EBS and directly save to S3?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS provides both Multi-Zone failover and the ability to create automated daily backups. Its a very good solution when you require redundant MySQL.

However, bear in mind that you need to get your performance metrics right, as once you deploy an Amazon RDS instance, you can't configure key metrics like max connections. You are tied to the max number of connections available per the instance you use. In that case, if you need to scale, you need to deploy a new RDS instance.

The Amazon Linux AMI  is also very good. Its well maintained and the RPM repos are kept up to date. You can also add 3rd party repos if required.

Being able to build up a server stack from a very lean base is much better than deploying something like RH with all the crud it ships with.